# Passing an array of strings from managed C# to unmanaged function using P-Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

Is it possible to pass a string array from managed C# to an unmanaged function using P-Invoke?

This works fine:

```
[DllImport("LibraryName.dll")]
private static extern void Function_Name(string message);
```

While this:

```
[DllImport("LibraryName.dll")]
private static extern void Function_Name(string[] message);
```

fails with

> Unhandled exception: System.NotSupportedException: NotSupportedException

I have tried using `MarshalAs` with no luck `([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String[] dataToLoadArr)`

Is it possible to pass string arrays this way?

Comment: What's the message on the exception?  Also, what is the declaration of the unmanaged function?

Comment: is [this](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/15480/P-Invoke-and-string-array) helpful?

Comment: Thanks, mtijn, that helped. Solved by using IntPtr structures representing the strings to be marshaled.

Comment: This works fine when I try it, no manual marshaling required.  There is a nasty flaw in the approach though, the native code has no way to tell how large the array is.  An extra argument is required.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Is this Windows CE or something like that?

Comment: This is running on an embedded system. I am quite sure it is Windows CE, yes.

Comment: Windows CE has different marshalling than normal windows which is why the code works for Hans Passant, but not for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport(Library)]
private static extern IntPtr clCreateProgramWithSource(Context context,
                                                       cl_uint count,
                                                       [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)] string[] strings,
                                                       [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysUInt, SizeParamIndex = 1)] IntPtr[] lengths,
                                                       out ErrorCode errcodeRet);
public static Program CreateProgramWithSource(Context context,
                                                 cl_uint count,
                                                 string[] strings,
                                                 IntPtr[] lengths,
                                                 out ErrorCode errcodeRet)
```

This works fine in my OpenCL library, OpenCL.NET (http://openclnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94246#1251571). Note that I am passing in the count using SizeParamIndex as well.